# find the frequency of three words that are in the list co-occured in combination in the given document

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, counting

I have multiple .txt files in desktop loaded as a data frame in python. I am working in python in the data frame, where 'text' is the name of the column that is my interest. Column 'text' consists of multiple .txt documents.

I also have three lists of words in mind: these are:

```
credit=['borrow', 'lend'],
policy=['Fed', 'fund rate','zero'],
trade=['deficit', 'surplus'],
```

My goal is to construct the index that measures the frequency of any of the words from the three lists in combination in a given sentence in the text file by applying it for each document separately. For example if 'borrow', 'fund' and 'surplus' co-occurred in a given sentence, it will`enter code here` be counted as 1.

## I know how to do it to count using a single word as follows:

```
my_dir_path ='C:/Users/desktop'
results = defaultdict(list)
for file in Path(my_dir_path).iterdir():
    with open(file, "r") as file_open:
        results["file_name"],(file.name)
        results["text"].append(file_open.read())
        df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

## to get the frequencty of the word policy across documents I used this code:

```
df['policy']=df['text'].apply(lambda x: len([word for word in x.split() if     word=='policy']))
```

How can I do it in python?
        Thanks in advance for any help?

Comment: what have you tried?  the dataframe detail just seems to be related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58467374/1358308) but otherwise unrelated to the current problem

Comment: I did not try because I have no idea. I know how to do it just based on the frequency of  a single word.

Comment: maybe you could modify your question to show how you'd do it for that single word?  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some help about getting useful answers.  another detail that would be useful to include in your question would be a definition of "a sentence".  e.g. `ntlk` has a "sentence tokenizer" for english is that OK?

Comment: Here what I used for single word:

Comment: df['policy']=df['text'].apply(lambda x: len([word for word in x.split() if  word=='policy']))

Comment: sentence tokenizer definiation of sentence works fine here.

Comment: please edit the question to include that code, and use the formatting options to make it look nice!  also where does `df` come from?  this isn't anywhere near a reproducible question at the moment

Comment: note that your code using `split()` probably doesn't do the right thing.  e.g. it doesn't find the word in `"policy."` because you're splitting on whitespace and there isn't any between `policy` and `.`

Comment: You are correct.  I should tokonize the document first.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use regular expressions for doing the matching of words within sentences, using lookahead/behind we could use something like:

```
(?<!\w)borrow(?!\w)
```

and would find "borrow" in `"can I borrow that"` and `"will borrow."` but not `"borrowing"`.  I'm unsure what you actually want to do here, but I'd suggest learning how to use regular expressions as they would allow you to express these options easily

to make the following code shorter, I define a function to compile a "word" into a regex object:

```
import re

def matcher(word):
    return re.compile(fr'(?<!\w){word}(?!\w)', re.IGNORECASE)

re_credit = [
    matcher('borrow'),
    matcher('fund'),
]
```

next I write a function to split a string up into sentences so we can count co-occurances of words:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

def count_sentences_matching_words(text, regexes):
    count = 0
    for sentence in sent_tokenize(text):
        if all(reg.search(sentence) for reg in regexes):
            count += 1
    return count
```

next we can test it with some text:

```
para = "My goal is to construct the index that measures the frequency of any of the words from the three lists in combination in a given sentence in the text file by applying it for each document separately. For example if 'borrow', 'fund' and 'surplus' co-occurred in a given sentence, it willenter code here be counted as 1."

count_sentences_matching_words(para, re_credit)
```

if you wanted to use this with pandas you could do the obvious:

```
df['credit'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: count_sentences_matching_words(x, re_credit))
```

it's probably worth rearranging this code, e.g. just doing the sentence tokenization once per file.  but it would depend on more details than you've shared

Comment: Yes, your code works fine for the context you provided.  However, my goal is to match the words from the lsit of words as explained:

Comment: the list are: credit=['borrow', 'lend'],
policy=['Fed', 'fund rate','zero'],
trade=['deficit', 'surplus'],

Comment: you can easily modify the above code to match those words!  I'd suggest working through some tutorials if you're still struggling, stackoverflow isn't a code writing service